# What does the raw value for the get_bloginfo's filter argument exactly do?

Tags: codex

The `$filter` argument for the `get_bloginfo` function has a default value of `raw` but WordPress' Code Reference didn't mention another allowed values. What this `raw` stands for and what are other possible values if any?

Comment: It's a good question. According to the source code, it can be `display`. As I understand, it's not accomplished up to now, so there are only two options: `display` or `anything else except 'display'`.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but now what is the effect of both `raw` and `display` on a result like for example `bloginfo('url')`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have the following filters added by default ([source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/503d42fe6bcd2f45b3af78657686f8a27ccb0136/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L98-L103))

```
add_filter( 'bloginfo', 'wptexturize'   );
add_filter( 'bloginfo', 'convert_chars' );
add_filter( 'bloginfo', 'esc_html'      );
```

The `bloginfo` filter ([source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/503d42fe6bcd2f45b3af78657686f8a27ccb0136/wp-includes/general-template.php#L748-L778)) is applied on the `get_bloginfo()` output, in the `display` mode, except for the *url* that has it's own `bloginfo_url` filter. The core isn't using that *url* filter currently and there's a *wontfix* (see [#26803](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/26803)) on escaping the *url* in display mode.

So the *raw* mode, skips these filters.

The `bloginfo()` function is a wrapper for `get_bloginfo()` in display mode ([source](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/503d42fe6bcd2f45b3af78657686f8a27ccb0136/wp-includes/general-template.php#L596)).